# Any individual or any individuals?

Tags: any-every

[The Newyorker](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/closeread/2013/04/obama-on-boston-the-question-of-terror.html) reports:

“Any responsible individuals, any responsible groups will feel the full weight of justice,” Obama said.

What is correct? 'Any responsible individual' or 'Any responsible individuals'? Similarly, shouldn't we say, 'Any responsible group' as opposed to 'Any responsible groups'?

Comment: Why would you think the plural could be incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

You can say any of those constructs and they'll be grammatically correct. Still, *the emphasis* changes.

When you say *any individual* you actually don't care about which one of the individuals you refer to. But when you say *any individuals* you it doesn't matter for the speaker how many individuals, but what matters that number of those individuals will be positive.

I think, of course, what was actually meant, that **"All individuals will feel the full weight of justice"**.