# Do we use 'any' with a countable noun?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I am an English tutor. I also lived in the USA for 2 years. Today when I was explaining to my student the use of 'any' in questions and negations, I got stuck. I know we use it before countable nouns in plural and we use it before an uncountable noun. But from my experience speaking English on a daily basis back in the USA I remember people using 'any' with a singular countable noun. For example, 'Is there any room available?'. What are your thoughts on that? Maybe it's the matter of British and American English?

Comment: I would take that to be the uncountable *room* meaning *space*.

Comment: It isn't clear what the confusion is.  There are two ways to interpret that sentence.  Jim's comment refers to the uncountable.  It could also apply to countable rooms (say a hotel), and the question is whether any one of the many is available.  Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Any fish could tell you it would prefer being thrown back in the water over being filleted.

Comment: "Any" is the counterpart of "some" in negative contexts (including questions), and that "any" can be used with a singular count noun, as can the "any" of a generalization, as in @Spencer's example.

Answer (score 0):

'Is there any room available?' Whether the room here is countable or uncountable (meaning space), any can be used with it as explained below:

NOTE: The following text and screen shots attached are from *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan

> '**Any**' can be used to emphasise the idea of 'free choice', with the meaning of 'it doesn't matter who/which/what'. With this meaning, any is common in affirmative clauses as well as questions and negatives, and is often used with singular countable nouns as well as uncountables and plurals."
>
> Examples:
>
> *She goes out with any boy who asks her.*
> *Can get a meal here at any time of the day?*
> *I don't do just any work - I choose jobs that interest me.*
>
> But, '**any**' can be used with plurals and uncountables in the same meaning as the article **a/an** has with singular countable nouns. With this meaning, '**any**' is unusual with singular countable nouns.
>
> Examples:
>
> *Is there  a tin-opener in the house? And, are there any plates?*
> *She hasn't got a job. **NOT** She hasn't got any job.*
> *Do you know a good doctor?* **NOT** *Do you know any good doctor?*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Practically identical to an earlier answer of yours. Is this an extract from Michael Swan's PEU book? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373575/of-any-mall-vs-of-any-malls

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, I've added screen shots.